# file system as hyperlinks in Jenkins console

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have to log a file system path in the Jenkins log after it completes the run. I know `echo 'file://filesystem/folder'` will be logged as a hyperlink in Jenkins pipeline, however clicking on it doesn't seem working. Is there a way to click on the link which will be redirected to `file/folder` system in your computer?

Comment: is `filesystem/folder` outside your $JENKINS_HOME or inside?

Comment: outside, so basically im writing a log file in some network location in file system and i want to just give that network path in Jenkins log. Should to able to click on path directly on Jenkins console itself. file://filesystem/folder is displayed as link however since there are forward slashes, click will not work, so i need that to be as backward slash to open the file system

Comment: is copying the file into the job's workspace an option, using a simple Execute Shell script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm providing this answer assuming that it's okay for you to copy the file in question from outside `$JENKINS_HOME` into the job's archive.

Within the job, in a build or post-build phase `Execute Shell` box:

```
cp $FILE_PATH $JENKINS_HOME/jobs/$JOB_NAME/builds/$BUILD_ID/archive
```

Where you only need to replace $FILE_PATH and the rest of parameters are known to Jenkins. A hyperlink to the last built file will appear in the list of the job's artifacts, visible on the job's main page, as well as in each build, specific to it.

Comment: file://\\networkpath\.filename is what i did instead of complex approaches. however the problem is i cannot access the file in Chrome browser, but IE working in this approach